# How do I go about telling Captcha that my form exists?

Tags: forms, captcha

I've got a drupal situation where I want to add reCaptcha to a custom form (built in an add-on module).  You can see from the captcha admin page that there is a list of forms that I can dynamically add captcha to... but my problem is that the form I created in the add-on does not appear in this list.

I'm sure I'm missing something (perhaps in the `myform_block_info` function?)

Does anyone know what hook I'm looking for?  Have a working example?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This was embarrassingly easy.  See that box at the bottom of the table?  Put your form ID in there.  "myform_form"

[image]