# reCaptcha does not display

Tags: 8, captcha

I've installed Captcha and reCaptcha in Drupal 8 because I want to use it on the site contact form. I believe I have all the configuration options set correctly but they are limited. For example, there is no place to tell it what form I want it to appear on.

All modules and core are up to date.

I am logging out to test the form. I know that by default administrators are not presented the reCaptcha.

I'm working with image based reCaptcha v2.

I've looked for a field widget to add to the form but there is nothing. Nor is there anything in the form display settings.

In the old days there was a form list to select from (see screenshots on this question: [How do I go about telling Captcha that my form exists?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17299/how-do-i-go-about-telling-captcha-that-my-form-exists) ) but that no longer appears.

The instructions even reference the missing list:

[image: there is no list!]

While reCaptha has a stable release for 8, Captcha has only a beta from Feb 2017. So I'm wondering if anyone has this working in 8 at all.

Any suggestions? Further troubleshooting steps I can take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Go to CAPTCHA Points and enable reCaptcha for your form.